# Use the LAN port as a WAN port replacement?

Tags: networking, router

I have a Zyxel P-660HW router which has worked just fine till date. I got a new internet connection which uses an ethernet cable for the WAN connection with PPPoE setup. My wireless router's DSL port can only accommodate a telephone cable. I heard that one of the LAN ports can be used as a WAN port.

Does any one know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Can't use another port but you can do Traffic Redirect / WAN backup which sends the traffic through another gateway when the connection is down.

[Zyxel P-660HW User Guide - 5.7 Traffic Redirect / 5.8 Configuring WAN Backup](ftp://ftp2.zyxel.com/P-660HW-D3/user_guide/P-660HW-D3_3.40_Ed1.pdf#page=89)

Comment: Has anyone succeeded with this method? The only info about setting this up is the pdf linked above. All it does is describe all the fields on the form one by one - setting them all up - no connection.